# Advantage of asio::streambuf over raw array

Tags: c++, arrays, boost-asio, streambuf

I don't quite understand the advantage of using streambuf over the regular array.
Let me explain my problem. I have a network connection which is encrypted using Rijndael 128 ECB + some easy cipher to encrypt remaining data that is shorter than 16 bytes. The packets are structured as length_of_whole_packet+operationcode+data. I have to actually copy all the data from the streambuf so I can apply decryption algorithm? Why making another copy of data I already have?

Same problem I have with the sending data. When in securedmode the packet structure is length_of_whole_packet+crc+data, where crc and data is encrypted. I could make some monstrosity as MakePacket(HEADER, FORMAT, ...) that would allocate array, format the packet, add crc and encrypt it, but I would like to avoid vararg function. I can't use structs as the packets has dynamic length because there can be arrays in it, or strings. If I used MakePacket(unsigned char opcode, &streambuf sb) then there would be problem with the crc again -> have to make a copy to encrypt it.

Should I use the vararg monstrosity for sending using regular array as buffer in combination with unsigned char pbyRecvBuffer[BUFFERMAXLEN] for recv?

I'm not really sure how to design this communication with avoiding copies of data.

Thank you for you answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `streambuf`s, copying of data can often be minimized by using algorithms that operate on iterators, such as `std::istreambuf_iterator` or [`boost::asio::buffers_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffers_iterator.html), rather than copying data from a `streambuf` into another data structure.

For stream-like application protocols, [`boost::asio::streambuf`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/streambuf.html) is often superior to [`boost::asio::buffer()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html) compatible types, such as a raw array.  For example, consider [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), where a delimiter is used to identify boundaries between variable length headers and bodies.  The higher-level [`read_until()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until.html) operations provide an elegant way to to read the protocol, as Boost.Asio will handle the memory allocation, detect the delimiter, and invoke the completion handler once the message boundary has been reached.  If an application used a raw array, it would need to read chunks and copy each fragmented chunk into an aggregated memory buffer until the appropriate delimiter was identified.

If the application can determine the exact amount of bytes to read, then it may be worth considering using `boost::array` for fixed length portions and `std::vector` for the variable length portions.  For example, an application protocol with a:

- fixed length body could be read into a `boost::array`.
- fixed length header that contains enough information to determine the length of the following variable length body could use a `std::vector` to read the fixed size header, resize the `vector` once the body length has been determined, then read the body.

In context of the question, if `length_of_whole_packet` is of a fixed length, the application could read it into `std::vector`, resize the `vector` based on the determined body length, then read the remaining data into the `vector`.  The decryption algorithm could then operate directly on the `vector` and use an output iterator, such as `std::back_insert_iterator`, with an auxiliary output buffer if the algorithm cannot be done in-place.  The same holds true for encrypting data to be written.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. I actually used streambuf in one of my older projects - HTTPS client. So my question was actually bit stupid :).

Well I have dropped out the streambuf in this project, as there is no convenient way how to use block cipher as Rijndael and decrypt/encrypt in place after the data is read/prepared_to_send. I went for static arrays. One big enough to be able to handle even the most big packets from recv and for send I'm still thinking if I should make it dynamically allocated raw array (the problem is calculating the size of packet before allocating the space).